# Como extrair dados específicos de um arquivo texto com python e armazenar em uma variavel

Tags: python

Bom dia, eu tenho um arquivo de texto com mais de 2mil cupons fiscais , porém eu queria extrair um por um apenas pelo valor, por enquanto meu código está assim:

```py
import re

txt = open("arqEspelho.txt", "r")

x = re.findall("^cotia", txt)

z = re.findall("ibpt$", txt)

for linhas in txt:
   if x and z and "172,20":

    print("tem")

else:

    print("No match")
```

porém eu não consigo retornar o cupom

eu preciso dizer a função que a palavra *"COTIA"* é o inicio do cupom e a palavra *"IBPT"* é o fim de um cupom e se determinado valor estiver entre essas palavras , ele me retorne esse cupom.

desde já agradeço.

Comment: Coloca uma parte do arquivo arqEspelho.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Nao sei como é seu `arqEspelho.txt` então criei um para apresentar uma possível solução

`arqEspelho.txt`

```
cotia
1 pao 10,00
2 carnes 20,00
ibpt
cotia
1 batata 15,00
2 cerveja 172,20
3 calabresa 25,50
ibpt
cotia
1 feijao 22,00
2 paio 12,45
3 laranja 32,23
ibpt
```

### Solução

```
import re

txt = open("arqEspelho.txt", "r").read()

# usando finditer ele retorna a posição da palavra
x = re.finditer(r"cotia", txt)
z = re.finditer(r"ibpt", txt)

# estou considerando que o arquivo possui a mesma quantidades de "cotia" e "ibpt"
# e que elas abrem e fecham cada espelho respectivamente
espelhos = list(zip(x, z))

# Testando o valor específico para cada espelho
for espelho in espelhos:
    txt_espelho = txt[espelho[0].span()[0]: espelho[1].span()[1]+1]
    if "172,20" in txt_espelho:
       print("Tem")
    else:
       print("Nao tem")
```

A saída será

```
Nao tem
Tem
Nao tem
```

**Atualização a partir do comentário**

Para imprimir o espelho especîfico

```
for espelho in espelhos:
    txt_espelho = txt[espelho[0].span()[0]: espelho[1].span()[1]+1]
    if "172,20" in txt_espelho:
       print(txt_espelho)
```

A saída será

```
cotia
1 batata 15,00
2 cerveja 172,20
3 calabresa 25,50
ibpt
```

Comment: Isto , mas teria como retornar o cupom na saída ao invés de "Tem" ?

Comment: Use print(txt_espelho)

Comment: Boa noite amigo , sou de de novo teria como retornar a linha de baixo tipo a linha abaixo do IBPT , pois a linha de baixo gera números aleatorios e não tem como achar com o finditer , desde já agradeço!

Comment: Retomo o comentário feito pelo `Bernardo Lopes`, coloque uma parte do arquivo arqEspelho.txt. Talvez seja melhor aceitar esta resposta como solução de sua pergunta inicial e iniciar outra pergunta.